# MsBuild- Delete files from a directory based on time modified / name

Tags: build, msbuild, cmd, msbuild-4.0

I have a list of files generated on each build inside a directory `C:\BuildArtifacts`

The Contents of a directory looks like this:

```
TestBuild-1.0.0.1.zip
TestBuild-1.0.0.2.zip
TestBuild-1.0.0.3.zip
TestBuild-1.0.0.4.zip
TestBuild-1.0.0.5.zip
TestBuild-1.0.0.6.zip
```

Now, with each incremental build, I just want to retain two recent artifacts and delete the rest. So, in this example, I want to retain `TestBuild-1.0.0.5.zip` and `TestBuild-1.0.0.6.zip`

How can I do it with MSBuild?

### Note:

I have managed to fetch the above list in an item

```
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(Artifacts)\.." Command="dir /B /A:-D /O:-N" Outputs="ArchiveFileList" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, we wrote a custom task to sort the files by their name and then output the list of the files to delete (excluding the first two in the list) into an `Item`

Custom Task:

```
 <UsingTask
    TaskName="Cleanup"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
      <TargetPath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true"/>
      <BackupLength ParameterType="System.Int32" Required="true"/>
      <FilesToExclude ParameterType="System.String[]" Output="true" />
      <FilesToDelete ParameterType="System.String[]" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Linq" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
        var diInfo = new DirectoryInfo(TargetPath);
            if (diInfo.Exists)
            {
                var fiInfo = diInfo.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(file => file.Name);

                FilesToExclude = fiInfo.Take(BackupLength).Select(file => file.FullName).ToArray();
                FilesToDelete = fiInfo.Skip(BackupLength).Select(file => file.FullName).ToArray();
            }
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

**Usage**:

```
<!-- Clean old archives. Keep the recent two and deletes rest. -->
<Cleanup TargetPath="$(PackageRoot)" BackupLength="2">
  <Output TaskParameter="FilesToDelete" ItemName="FilesToClean" />
</Cleanup>

<Message Text="Cleaning Old Archives" Importance="High" />
<Delete Files="@(FilesToClean)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Please test this command then `<exec ...>` it with `del` instead of `echo`:

```
for /f %x in ('cmd /c "dir /B /A-D /O-N | more +2"') do echo %x
```

Comment: The accepted answer is good, but I have to admit this single line answer is pretty bad ass!